# How do I place Stack Overflow flair on my Twitter profile?

Tags: discussion, flair, twitter

Has anyone tried to place a Stack Overflow flair to a Twitter profile page?
I'd like very much to have the one with the **hot dog stand** theme over there, heh heh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all Twitter allows you to do is changing the background image and the colors, you'll have to constantly re-upload your flair image everytime it changes.

You *could* run a cron job somewhere that regularly checks if your flair has changed, create a new profile background image that includes your flair, and use Twitter's [update_profile_background_image](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0update_profile_background_image) API method to update it.

Answer (score 6):

For the love of all that is holy, please don't put your fluorescent unicorn avatar onto the hotdog themed flair onto your twitter!

***My eyes!  The goggles do nothing!***

Edit:

With the new image based flair you can easily add your flair to your twitter page.  Just use the image `https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/72746.png?theme=hotdog` (replace 72746 with your user number if you aren't the OP) in the design section of your twitter profile ( http://twitter.com/settings/design - under "Change background image" )

[image]

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair to get the image code for the combined flair, if you're into that.

Comment: In before 'what has been seen, cannot be unseen.'

Comment: but, that's just my reasoning! ;)